# How to print class attributes in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Resize Class

```
class Resize {

    int width = 12

    int length = 10

}
```

I have this method to print data from Resize class

```
 public String print(){
    Resize resize = new Resize()
    println(resize)
 }
```

How to dynamically print values like this? I mean what if I don't know the key names.

```
[12, 10]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple util function like this:

```
class Resize {
    int width = 12;
    int length = 10;

    String getDimensionsAsString(){

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("[");

        sb.append(width);
        sb.append(",");

        sb.append(length);

        sb.append("]");

        return sb.toString();

    }

}

println new Resize().getDimensionsAsString();
```

---

Output:

```
[12,10]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the class with [ToString](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/transform/ToString.html)

e.g.

```
import groovy.transform.ToString

@ToString(includeNames=true)
class Resize { ...
```

If the output from ToString isn't suitable you could try:

```
class Resize {   

    int width = 12      
    int length = 10 

    String toString() {
        properties.findAll{it.key != 'class'}.collect{ it.value }
    }
}
```

Comment: good to know; but this will print ```Resize(width:12, length:10)```